# Validate an mDNS address using pure Regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-group, mdns

I need to validate whether a given string is a valid mDNS address. Examples of these are listed here:

```
a2aadd61-85d9-4be6-a36c-267ad65917d3.local
ccd58700-cdd5-4c1f-8098-5bc306f1ce77.local
bb4115cd-1f39-42b0-9433-e59533c9c771.local
3b382824-24bf-457a-a7d6-b6e25e4d79bf.local
9284cbaa-2933-45e3-9ae2-c0cccae54b68.local
619281fb-6426-44fa-8d0f-9e58ce415e3e.local
541d8a99-b1a5-46f4-96f1-e31f30b3cb99.local
2feb782f-ea40-4a37-b843-5b5b4fe1860e.local
```

Is this possible? I am new to regex and can't seem to find any regex examples for this particular string.
This was my attempt at making a regex test:

```js
let valid = 'a2aadd61-85d9-4be6-a36c-267ad65917d3.local';
let invalid = 'not-valid-233q4q22eqwr-q3rhHE02n333r4tsefs.local';

let regex = \([a-zA-Z1-9]+){8}-([a-zA-Z1-9]){4}-([a-zA-Z1-9]){4}-([a-zA-Z1-9]){12}\.local\;

regex.test(valid)
```

Comment: First, the regex literal delimiters are not correct. It has to be slash and not backslash. Second, the `+` quantifier of the first character class of exactly eight characters is not needed (even wrong). Third, the sub-sequence of "4 characters plus dash" appears 3 times in a row. The OP's regex does not reflect this (it covers it just 2 times). Fourth, in addition to all that, the grouping into parenthesis is of no use. Thus, a regex which fixes and optimizes everything said needs to look close to ... [`/^[a-z\d]{8}(?:-[a-z\d]{4}){3}-[a-z\d]{12}\.local$/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/6KWLm9/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, the regex literal delimiters are not correct. It has to be slash and not backslash.
- Second, the `+` quantifier of the first character class of exactly eight characters is not needed (even wrong).
- Third, the sub-sequence of *"4 characters plus dash"* appears 3 times in a row. The OP's regex does not reflect this (it covers it just 2 times).
- Fourth, in addition to all that, the grouping into parenthesis is of no use. Thus, a regex which fixes and optimizes everything said needs to look close to ... [`/^[a-z\d]{8}(?:-[a-z\d]{4}){3}-[a-z\d]{12}\.local$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/6KWLm9/1).

```js
const regXAddress =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/6KWLm9/1]
  /^[a-z\d]{8}(?:-[a-z\d]{4}){3}-[a-z\d]{12}\.local$/i;

const testSample =
`a2aadd61-85d9-4be6-a36c-267ad65917d3.local
ccd58700-cdd5-4c1f-8098-5bc306f1ce77.local
bb4115cd-1f39-42b0-9433-e59533c9c771.local
3b382824-24bf-457a-a7d6-b6e25e4d79bf.local
9284cbaa-2933-45e3-9ae2-c0cccae54b68.local
619281fb-6426-44fa-8d0f-9e58ce415e3e.local
541d8a99-b1a5-46f4-96f1-e31f30b3cb99.local
2feb782f-ea40-4a37-b843-5b5b4fe1860e.local
2feb782f-e2a40-4a37-b843-5b5b4fe1860e.local
2feb78f-ea40-4a37-b8432-5b5b4fe1860e.local
2feb78f-ea40-4a37-b8432-5b5b4fe1860.local`;

console.log(
  testSample
    .split(/\n/)
    .map(address =>
      `'${ address }' is ${ regXAddress.test(address) ? '' : 'in' }valid`
    )
    .join('\n')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Although this is a very old question, the new answer is appreciated. Thanks for helping out with my very limited knowledge of regex!

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work using this:

```js
let valid = 'a2aadd61-85d9-4be6-a36c-267ad65917d3.local';
let invalid = 'not-valid-233q4q22eqwr-q3rhHE02n333r4tsefs.local';

let regex = /(^[a-zA-Z1-90]{8})-([a-zA-Z1-90]{4})-([a-zA-Z1-90]{4})-([a-zA-Z1-90]{4})-([a-zA-Z1-90]{12})\.local/;

console.log(regex.test(valid)) //=> true
console.log(regex.test(invalid)) //=> false
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>

Comment: @divinelemon ... even though your own solution now solves its purpose `[a-zA-Z1-90]` can be shortened to two ranges within the character class `[a-z0-9]` and even more to `[a-z\d]` (due to `\d` covering the range of all decimal characters). The 2nd range of `A-Z` is not needed as soon as one sets the case **i**nsensitive flag. And of cause one can shorten the literal repetition of 3 times `-([a-zA-Z1-90]{4})` to `(-[a-z\d]{4}){3}` or even `(?:-[a-z\d]{4}){3}`.